# SQL Server - smart approach for combining GUID and identity column

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to come up with a design for my database where across all my tables I'd like to have the combination of a `GUID` column (`uniqueidentifier` data type) and an identity column (`int` data type).

The `GUID` column is going to be a `NONCLUSTERED` index whilst the identity column is going to be the `CLUSTERED` index. I was wondering if the script below is a correct/safe approach when it comes to database design:

```
CREATE TABLE country 
(
    guid uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWID() NOT NULL,
    code int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    isoCode nvarchar(5) NOT NULL,
    description nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    created date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    updated date NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    inactive bit DEFAULT 0

    CONSTRAINT NIX_guid PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED(guid),
    CONSTRAINT AK_code UNIQUE(code),
    CONSTRAINT AK_isoCode UNIQUE(isoCode)
)
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_code] ON country ([code] ASC)
GO
```

That's how it looks after running the above script:

[image]

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you defining **two** columns that both could be the primary key on their own? What **benefit** do you expect to get from having both a `Guid` and an `INT IDENTITY` column at the same time??

Comment: `GUID` - external use, unique across all tables/servers, easy to merge records ,synchronizing data with an external source (could cause bad performance in the long term); `INT IDENTITY` long term performance (indexed), sorting etc.

Comment: @marc_s quite a few SQL experts recommend having an int identity to improve performance when using a guid primary key. I have even done it myself, but I've never found a clear reasoning as to exactly how it helps.

Comment: Consider `DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()` for the primary key, make it clustered, and ditch the identity. This will provide many of the benefits of an incremental key without a redundant surrogate key and index.

Comment: @DaleK: I've "fixed" some botched up tables that had their clustered PK on a Guid column with this approach (suggested by Kimberly Tripp). And it really helped quite a bit, to improve search and query performance - at the cost of some additional disk space taken by the `INT IDENTITY` column. This approach really does work quite nicely - the question in my mind is - why does it need an extra `Guid`  column? Why isn't an `INT IDENTITY` as clustered PK sufficient ?

Comment: What does the uniqueidentifier actually represent? Naming the column *guid* conveys as much meaning as calling an integer column *int* - what name would you give a second uniqueidentifier?

Comment: @DaleK - having a `GUID` column has some advantages among which are: unique across all tables/servers, easy to merge records as you have no risk getting in conflict with an identity column holding the same values, synchronizing data with an external source and lots more.

Comment: _long term performance (indexed), sorting etc._ this is a pretty vague reason to have another int column. Is this int a foreign key to another table? What is it used for? Is the int the real key for everything and the guid is just a globally unique record identifier? This seems a bit like overbaking to me. You should probably carefully consider what purpose each of these columns have and which one will actually be the functional key that joins to other tables. If it's not the guid then I say the guid is redundant.

Comment: I'd suggest you should find better unique keys for your tables. Even one surrogate key is arguable, two is just excessive.

Answer (score 2):

The domain of all possible countries is never going to be more than a few hundred, so performance should not be a concern.

You already have an `isoCode`. That is a canonically defined candidate key. I understand what you mean when talking about GUIDs being useful because they can never collide when created on separate servers/application instances/etc. But ISO country codes can never collide either, because they're already defined by an external authority. You don't need the GUID.

Why is your existing `isoCode` column an `nvarchar(5)`? There is a 2 letter, and a 3 letter, ISO3166 standard. There are no unicode characters required, so you can use `char(2)` or `char(3)` depending on which standard you pick, both of which would be narrower than a 4 byte `int`.

Yes, an identity-based clustered index does mean not having to worry about page splits on insert. But these are *countries*. We already know all of the countries you need to insert right now, and are you really worried that the handful of changes that might be made over the next few decades will kill the performance of your system due to page splits on insert? No, so you don't need the identity column either.

Eliminate both surrogates, and just go with the alpha-2 or alpha-3 ISO country code as your clustered primary key.

Comment: I understand the reasoning - thanks! Point the above scenario is just an example and I was asking more from a whole database design as I was thinking to implement a standardized solution. Will you choose both `identity` and `isoCode` in this scenario or just `isoCode`? What if for a `customer` + `supplier` + `addresses` - would it make sense to have a combination of `guid` and `identity`?

Comment: @cdrrr I would only use `isoCode`, the `identity` isn't adding any value in this case. Other cases may be different, it depends on what your candidate keys are. Unfortunately there's no "single rule" you can follow in all cases. But in the case of something that *does* have a canonical, well defined key (like ISO country codes) always use them, they make the GUIDs unnecesary. You *might* still want a surrogate identity in some cases. If you really do have distributed data generation you might want a surrogate GUID, but even if you do, use `newsequentialid` (per Dan Guzman's comment).

Comment: @cdrrr ...Of course, if you have data being generated independently by multiple systems, and they all need to eventually coalesce into the single database, you can't use `newsequentialid` (since that is generated within the context of one system, at the database level). But even then, I'd first be asking "do I really not have any candidate *natural* key?". Transactional data often requires some kind of surrogate, but reference data nearly always has a natural key of some sort. Only then consider adding an identity column as a surrogate (unique, narrow, static, ever increasing) to avoid splits.

Comment: @cdrrr And even if you *do* have multiple independent systems, that still doesn't *necessarily* mean a GUID is your only solution. If you control all of the nodes you can assign each node its own unique key (like, a single letter, for example), and then have a two column key on the central system being the combination of the node-specific identity column plus the system key (which will not eliminate splits, but it certainly makes them much less frequent)

Comment: `newsequentialid` will be globally unique across multiple generating systems; it just won't be globally sequential.  Each generating system will generate GUIDs at a different point in the GUID sort order.

Comment: Yes, I probably should have said "won't get the advantages of `newsequentialid` as mentioned by Dan" rather than "can't use it", But my comment was already full.